# Check for unsaved changes and ask user to save

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing an extension which adds files to projects in the solution.

It makes sense to check first for unsaved changes and if there are any, ask user to save.

How can I achieve this?

Are there any open source VS extensions which do this so I can take a look how it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if there are unsaved changes, you can enumerate open documents with [DTE.Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.documents?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and check each one for the [Document.Saved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.document.saved?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) property.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to work with project via [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation?view=netframework-4.7.2) that has corresponding functional.

> Extension which adds files to projects in the solution.

After including new files to the project, they must be reevaluated. Pay your attention on [Project.IsDirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.isdirty?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_Project_IsDirty) property:

> A project is modified and must be reevaluated when the underlying
>   project source code, including changes to imported files. A project is
>   also modified must be reevaluated if the project tool set changes.

---

[Project.IsDirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.isdirty?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_Project_IsDirty) | [Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.reevaluateifnecessary?view=netframework-4.7.2) | [Project.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.save?view=netframework-4.7.2)