# How to get changed code lines in Visual Studio 2019 programmatically?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I want to make an extension for Visual Studio 2019 where I can go through  changed code lines (the lines which are marked as green/yellow) by clicking a button - a similar function like the "navigate Back/forward" button, but only for changed code lines.

Maybe it's possible to use the TextSnapShots
   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextsnapshot?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017),
   but it seems that you can't access the SnapShots which were created by Visual Studio - only the ones you created manually.

I've read this article but it doesn't help me, or maybe I missed something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/inside-the-editor?view=vs-2019

I'm new to DTE and can't find a collection of "changed text lines" or something similar in the DTE object structure. Do I have to create one by myself using `EnvDTE.TextDocument.LineChanged` event or something different?

Please tell me if you need more info or clearer explanations what my problem is.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672375/check-for-unsaved-changes-and-ask-user-to-save) can make some help.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Unfortunately not

Comment: Sorry for that not working. You can try [TextEditorEventsClass.LineChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.texteditoreventsclass.linechanged?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).