# How to detect files pending save?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to follow the Sergey [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682450)on this same question, on how to detect a file that have a "pending save state".

Code:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

namespace Link
{
    public static class ProjectHelpers
    {
        static ProjectHelpers()
        {
            // Rely on caller being on UI thread as shouldn't do it here in the constructor.
#pragma warning disable VSTHRD010 // Invoke single-threaded types on Main thread
            Dte = (DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));
#pragma warning restore VSTHRD010 // Invoke single-threaded types on Main thread
            Dte2 = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));
        }

        public static DTE Dte { get; }

        public static DTE2 Dte2 { get; }
    }
}
```

and then i'm calling Dte.Documents as:

```
try
{
      await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();

      // Enumerate through open documents
      foreach (Document doc in ProjectHelpers.Dte.Documents)
      {
         // Check if the document has unsaved changes
         if (!doc.Saved)
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unsaved changes in document: {doc.FullName}");
         }
      }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

But i'm getting this exception:

`The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000A)`

What i'm missing?

Comment: As the hresult suggest you probably call this when the documents list or the complete DTE subsystem isn't ready yet. So part of the problem is presumably "when" you do it. Is this already called in a VS startup routine?

Comment: I suspect the static constructor of `ProjectHelpers` is called before everything is ready.

Comment: @Ralf i tried calling it with a shortcut, `ProjectHelpers.Dte.ActiveDocument` works only `.Documents` doesnt.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria it doesnt, i'm able to use `dte` correctly as i mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the order of instantiation?